# Why to use SHA-1 in the publication of applications

Tags: notepad++, hashcode, sha1

I went to download Notepad++ and something called my attention, tha page presented some download choices (Installer,zip package,7z package, minimalist package,SHA-1 digests for binary packages,source code) the "SHA-1 digests for binary packages" choice makes me ask some questions, for what I know, SHA-1 generates a hashcode, so why is they using it? which is really the function of the hashcode in this case? Generally, which is the science of use it? I'm really new in this concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash comes into play when you download the executable from a mirror not controlled by the original website owner (I'll explain why it's only really useful for mirrors in a minute). Let's say someone replaces the executable with a version infected with some form of malware. How would you know? I mean Notepad++ is a trustworthy application so you're not likely to be skeptical. What you can do is download the application and compute the SHA-1. You can then compare this to the one on the website to make sure the file you downloaded is the one they say. Now the reason I said "from a mirror" is because, if the hacker hacked the Notepad++ website and replaced the exe, a smart hacker will also replace the SHA-1 listed on their site so it matches what's in the malware infected version.

Since most packages today are available from dozens of download mirrors that are outside of the control of the actual software author, the hashes (be they SHA-1, SHA-2, MD5, or any other hash) are a nice "double check" to make sure what you're downloading is what the original author intended you to download, even though it's coming from a server he/she doesn't control.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can locally calculate the SHA-1 hash of the files after downloading them, and then compare it to the published digests.

If the local hash does not correspond to the ones published by the authors of the package, there is something wrong: Either your download, the distributed package, or the list of hashes. Either way, you should not trust your download if that happens.